# Why and How to use sphinx morphology?

Tags: php, sphinx

I am currently working on sphinx. I have read about morphology from sphinx website. Check the following link but i think i did not get it well.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.1.1/conf-morphology.html

Can anybody please tell me why and how to use morphology in sphinx in simple way ?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: "Check the following link..." --- What link? :)

Answer (score 0):

The general overview, is make search more 'fuzzy'.

So that similar words will match. The exact definition of 'more fuzzy' depends on which processor you use.

Stemmers mean for example plural and singular words match. So that even if slightly different versions of the same base word are used, users can still match.

A Lemmatizer does the same thing, in a slightly different technical wal.

The Phonetic processors make words that sound the same match - so that dont have to be exact on spelling.